# Estrutura e Ponteiros em C: Árvore Binária

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados, alocação, árvore-binária

Olá, Estou tentando criar uma árvore de expressões matemáticas com a seguinte lógica:

minha expressão se trata de uma string, e eu tenho 4 opções de caracteres:

- ( : Ao encontrar esse caractere, meu código deve criar um nó para o `pref`, inserir em seu `conteudo(pref->conteudo)` o caractere '#', guardar o endereço do `pref` em um vetor de ponteiros do tipo pontNo chamado `endereco`,soma a variavel `k` (fazendo com que o vetor ande para próxima iteração) e fazer com que `pref` aponte para `pref->esq`.
- Algarismos(0 até 9): Cria um nó em `pref` e preenche seu `conteudo(pref->conteudo)` com o caractere do algarismo.
- Operador(+ - * /): Ao encontrar um operador, ele olha o último endereco do vetor `endereco`, faz com que `pref = endereco[k] (implicando que pref irá apontar para esse novo endereço)` para então `pref->conteudo` receber o caractere referente ao operador, após isso `pref = pref->dir(aponta para a direita)`.
- ): Diminui a variavel `k`, fazendo com que o referencial do vetor `endereco` diminua. 
  Caso facilite, pensei no vetor `endereco` com se fosse uma pilha em sí.

Essa era a minha ideia, entretanto estou obtendo sérios problemas de segment fault apesar de eu não conseguir pensar no que estou errando. O código segue abaixo divido no main e no arvbin.c
OBS: Meu intuito era ter um ponteiro se movimentando pela árvore (`pm`) e algo estático como referencial para a raiz, mas como eu disse estou tendo sérios problemas com o manuseio de ponteiros.
PS: Eu percebi em outras respostas que definir com typedef um ponteiro de uma estrutura é uma má prática de programação, entretanto esse foi o único jeito que consegui aprender para definir um ponteiro para uma estrutura x dentro dessa estrutura.

arvbin.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "arvbin.h"
    typedef struct no *pontNo;
    typedef struct no{
        char conteudo;
        pontNo esq;
        pontNo dir;
    }no;
    void CRIA_NO(pontNo novoNo,char info){
        novoNo = malloc(sizeof(no));
        novoNo->conteudo = info;
        novoNo->esq = NULL;
        novoNo->dir = NULL;

    }
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "arvbin.h"



int main() {
    //Declaracao de variaveis & Inicializacoes:
    no raiz; //Raiz da arvore declarada
    raiz.conteudo = '#'; //Declarando conteudo da raiz
    pontNo pm = &raiz; //(P)onteiro para (M)ovimentacao na arvore,inicialmente apontando para raiz
    pontNo endereco[20]; //Vetor de ponteiros para endereco do tipo pontNo, funcionara como uma pilha
    char expressao[100]; //Expressao matematica inserida
    int resultado;

    //Funcionamento:
    while(1){
        printf("Escreva a expressao matematica(Caso queira parar, escreva 0): ");
        scanf("%s",expressao);
        if(strcmp(expressao,"0") == 0) break; //Condicao de parada do loop de insercao de expressoes
        int k = 0;
        int error = 0;
        int i;      
        for(i = 0;expressao[i] != '\0';i++){
            if(expressao[i] == '('){
                if(i == 0){
                    endereco[k] = pm;
                    printf("%c\n",endereco[k]->conteudo);
                    k++;
                    pm = pm->esq;
                }
                else{
                    CRIA_NO(pm,'#');
                    endereco[k] = pm;
                    printf("%c\n",endereco[k]->conteudo);
                    k++;
                    pm = pm->esq;                   
                }
            }
            else if(expressao[i] == '0'||expressao[i] == '1'||expressao[i] == '2'||expressao[i] == '3'||expressao[i] == '4'||expressao[i] == '5'||expressao[i] == '6'||expressao[i] == '7'||expressao[i] == '8'||expressao[i] == '9'){
                    CRIA_NO(pm,expressao[i]);
                    printf("%c\n",pm->conteudo);                    
            }
            else if(expressao[i] == '+'||expressao[i] == '-'||expressao[i] == '*'||expressao[i] == '/'){

            }
            else if(expressao[i] == ')'){

            }
            else{
                printf("Erro na expressao: char nao reconhecido!\n");
                error = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Caso vocês tenham uma outra forma de resolver esse problema me avisem!

Comment: Qual a entrada que está a dar para essa árvore ? Vejo um `if` para um digito numérico, e como está a fazer para interpretar números com mais de 1 digito ? Tente tornar a sua lógica mais clara, dando exemplos de valores de entrada e saídas com a respetiva explicação da lógica aplicada.

Comment: Só vai entrar valores de 1 dígito, no caso a entrada é uma string de expressões ex: (2+3), no loop do for eu verifico cada item da string expressao